# What is the strength of the Earth's magnetic field at McMurdo Station, Antarctica?

Tags: geomagnetism, antarctica

Based on [this map](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/DoDWMM.shtml),

[image]

Below are images showing more specific detail.

[image]

[image]

I assume the field strength is between 0.6 gauss and 0.65 gauss, but I cannot tell between which ios-flux lines (if that is a legitimate term) McMurdo Station is located.  Are there precise measurements of the magnetic field strength at that location, within 0.01 gauss?

Comment: At co-ord 77 deg 51' S, 166 deg 40' E, [Mc Murdo Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McMurdo_Station) is just off the map. From my interpolation of where it lies, the magnetic field strength is close to 64 000 nT.

Answer (score 4):

According to the current [World Magnetic Model 2015 v2](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml#igrfwmm) (new one to be released on 10 December 2019!),

```
Longitude: 166.6863° E
Latitude: 77.8419° S
Elevation: 10 m

Date: 2019-11-25
Declination (+E | -W):   141.5232°    (-0.1829°/yr)
Inclination (+D | -U):   -80.3929°    (0.0399°/yr)
Horizontal Intensity:     10,396.8 nT (34.7 nT/yr)
North Comp (+N | -S):     -8,139.2 nT (-6.5 nT/yr)
East Comp (+E | -W):       6,468.8 nT (47.6 nT/yr)
Vertical Comp (+D | -U): -61,423.3 nT (54.8 nT/yr)
Total Field:              62,297.0 nT (-48.3 nT/yr)

Uncertainties:  0.57°   0.22°   133 nT  138 nT  89 nT   165 nT  152 nT
```